# Finding all holomorphic functions between half the plane and a quarter of the plane

Tags: complex-analysis

> Denote $$A=\{z:\rm{Re}(z) > 0\}$$$$B=\{z:\rm{Re}(z)>0, \rm{Im}(z)>0\}$$. Find all bijective holomorphic functions mapping $A$ to $B$.

I know that $\sqrt{z}$ is one such function, and I think it's the only one. But I have no idea how to approach proving something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the upper half plane $$
C=\{z:\rm{Im}(z) > 0\}.
$$
Let \begin{align}
\varphi (z)&=iz,\\
\psi(z)&=\frac{az+b}{cz+d},\quad (a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}, \,\,ad-bc>0)\\
\phi(z)&=\sqrt{z}.
\end{align}

Recall that \begin{align}
&\varphi : A\to C\,\,\text{bijectively},\\
&\psi : C\to C \,\,\text{bijectively},\\
&\phi : C\to B\,\,\text{bijectively}.
\end{align}

Therefore the general form of bijective holomorphic functions mapping $A$ to $B$ is $$
f(z)=\phi\circ\psi\circ\varphi (z)=\sqrt{\frac{iaz+b}{icz+d}},\quad (a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}, \,\,ad-bc>0).
$$
Examples. If we take $a=8,b=5,c=0$ and $d=1$, then we get $f(z)=\sqrt{8iz+5}= e^{i\pi/4}\sqrt {8z-5i}$. If we take $a=-2, b=-1, c=1$ and $d=0$, then we get $f(z)=\sqrt{\frac{i\pi}{z}-2}=e^{i\pi/4}\sqrt {\pi/z+2i}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Actually $\sqrt z$ isn't one such. Try $e^{i\pi/4}\sqrt z$ insead. Another one is $e^{i\pi/4}\sqrt {8z-5i}.$ Here's another:  $e^{i\pi/4}\sqrt {\pi/z+2i}.$